# CakePHP: How to add a callback to Auth::login() or Auth::logout()

Tags: php, cakephp, authentication

I'm running CakePHP v2.4 and the docs show several customization options for controlling the built-in Auth component behavior. However, I don't see anything about adding callbacks for after login() or logout().

I need run some other routines in conjunction with those actions, and it would be much DRYer for that code to live in a centralized callback rather than rewriting it everywhere that login() or logout() are called.

Comment: I have encountered this situation before. It does not seem to have this callback built-in.

Answer (score 3):

Extending `AuthComponent` as suggested by @Eisa Adil, is good, but I would recommend to use [Event](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/events.html). You will add `App::uses('CakeEventManager', 'Event');` and your extended login method could look like:

```
function login($user = null) { 
    CakeEventManager::instance()->dispatch(new CakeEvent('Auth.beforeLogin', $this, array('user' => $user)));
    $loggedIn = parent::login($user);
    CakeEventManager::instance()->dispatch(new CakeEvent('Auth.afterLogin', $this, array('user' => $user)));

    return $loggedIn; 
}
```

The you can define your callback in your [custom event listener](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/events.html#registering-listeners), so you can have many listeners (handy for plugins), outside the controller and you can even decide to stop the event in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

```
class UsersController extends AppController {

function afterLogin($successfully){ 
        if($successfully == true){ 
            // do something if logged successfully 
        }else{ 
            // do something if not 
        } 
    } 

}
```

[Read more.](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/lucaswxp/2011/02/02/adding_beforelogin_and_afterlogin_callbacks_authextended)

Comment: What calls `afterLogin()` in your answer?